# Class deriving design

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

This is the photo of my design. Sorry for not being crystal clear.

[image]

What is found in class A, is universal.
Classes B, C, D, E, F contain other custom functions.
By using this type of combinations of classes, I can solve the 8 problems.

Take for example the permutations problem. Is the first one, called G. Takes the information from B, C, and E and combines them so it can solve the problem.

The problem is that ...I don't know how to combine them.

This is the table with the functions.
[image]

Sorry for my whiteboard. It's quite old, and I didn't have any other paper for it.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean "have a nice interface"?  `D` already inherits the interface of `B` and `C`.

Comment: A dreaded diamond.. Do you really need inheritance to solve your problem? Some code would be appreciated. (N.B. There's even a [tag:diamond-problem] tag, though I'm not sure it applies here.)

Comment: Your end users of an interface should never be subclasses of the same interface! The client code should just use the classes via the highest level interface possible.

Comment: I have a problem. I must do in one program all these problems:
1. Permutations
2. Arrangements
3. Combinations
4. Cartesian
5. Partitions with natural numbers
6. Partitions with sets
7. Partitions with surjective sets
8. Queens Problem

All shall be done with the backtracking method. I saw that they have similarities between them. I want a class which contains the functions where I can use them in any problem. Then derived classes that contain some predefined functions to encompass everything I need for the problem and then 8 derived classes that uses this classes to solve the problem.

Comment: These are the functions:
1. init - found everywhere
2. display - found everywhere
3. backtrack - found everwhere
4. succesor 
5. valid
6. solution

Comment: Shall I post another question? I have also designed a model.

Comment: @RobertEagle Just edit this one please. Enhance with code sample and diagrams.

Comment: Ok. Wait a couple of minutes.

Comment: @RobertEagle - are you forcing a class hierarchy (meant to represent objects) onto a functional library of algorithms? You might find it useful to reuse code, but that does not necessarily mean that you must write classes. Just write algorithms as free functions in an appropriate namespace. 

You might want SOME classes perhaps to represent structures that you need (e.g. CarthesianPoint inheriting from Point) but in general they should only implement functionality for those objects (e.g "toPolar()"). Code examples, & names of your classes would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you and I are busy on almost the same type of inheritance structure. What I did was basically as follows. You define the functions that run through-out the inheritance as private functions of all the classes they are in. Then when they are called, you can do the following:

A.h

```
class A
{ private:
   int z;
public:
 ...constructors and destructors for A...
void print() const;
};
```

A.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
void A::print() const
{
   cout << "This class contains an int with value " << z << endl;
}
```

B.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
class B : public A
{
private:
   int i;
public:
...constructors and destructors...
void print() const;
};
```

B.cpp

```
#include "B.h"

void B::example() const
{
    cout << "This class contains ant with value: " << i << endl;
    A::print();
}
```

This way when you call the print() function on an object of type B, it will not only print it's member variable but it will also print the member variable of it's base class because you called the function.

You could also try using virtual functions

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/

Hope this is somewhat what you are looking for.

Comment: Can you be a little more explicit? I think I'm getting it, but I'm still confused.

Comment: @RobertEagle I edited my example to give a vivid illustration of what I mean, and I did double check to make sure it works (it does). Good luck

Comment: Yes. I understood it completely. As Dennis pointed out on the other thread as a comment, it looks like the class way might not be the optimum solution. I think that the optimum one would be like using imbricated namespaces. It works, yes, but the classes are somehow, ghostly, you get me? Anyway, I'll build both the solutions.